# GstAppSrc for large buffers

Tags: c, streaming, gstreamer

My pipeline is:

```
appsrc ! identity ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink
```

The buffers being passed to `appsrc` are 640*480 raw RGBA32 uncompressed byte arrays at 30fps - which is **terribly slow**. I'm using the `identity` element to measure how frequently it is receiving frames from `appsrc` using

```
g_signal_connect(data->identity, "handoff", cb_identity_handoff, data);
```

At 640*480 raw RGBA 32 bit uncompressed, the `identity` element receives frames at ~2fps.
Everything kept same, 320*240 raw frames give about ~12fps, and at 160*120 it gives a full 30fps. Is this a known issue with `GstAppSrc`?

---

**Extra info:**

No frames are being dropped by `appsrc`. They're all queued; I checked using `GST_BUFFER_PTS` to see if any of the frames are being dropped, by setting them while pushing them to `appsrc`, and reading them at `identity`.

**Code:**

Setting up `AppSrc`:

```
data->src = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(data->pipeline), "camsrc");

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data->src), "caps",
             gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw",
                                 "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGBA",
                                 "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,
                                 "height", G_TYPE_INT, 480,
                                 "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
                                  NULL), NULL);

gint64 frame_size = 640*480*4;
gint64 queue_size = 100*640*480*4;

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data->src),
             "stream-type", GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM,
             "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
             "block", FALSE,
             "max-bytes", queue_size,
             "size", frame_size,
             "is-live", TRUE,
             NULL);
```

Frames are fed from Java to C using the following function:

```
static void gst_add_stream(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray buffer, jint size, jlong ptime,
                           jlong custom_data) {
    CustomData *data = (CustomData *) (jint) custom_data;//GET_CUSTOM_DATA (env, thiz, custom_data);
    if (!data || size == 0) return;

    GstBuffer *gstbuffer;
    GstMapInfo map;
    GstFlowReturn ret;

    GstClockTime timestamp = ptime;

    jbyte *pbuffer = (jbyte *) (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, buffer, 0);

    // though I'm doing a memcopy here, and allocating, I've measured the time and it doesn't seem to be taking more than 2ms. Using CLOCK_REALTIME 
    gstbuffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, size, NULL);
    gst_buffer_map(gstbuffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
    memcpy((char *) map.data, pbuffer, (int) size);

    gst_buffer_unmap(gstbuffer, &map);

    GST_BUFFER_PTS(gstbuffer) = timestamp;
    LOGD("add_stream timestamp %"G_GUINT64_FORMAT, GST_BUFFER_PTS (gstbuffer));
    GST_BUFFER_DURATION(gstbuffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int(1, GST_SECOND, data->framerate);
    g_signal_emit_by_name(data->src, "push-buffer", gstbuffer, &ret);

    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
        g_debug("push buffer returned %d for %d bytes \n", ret, size);
    }

    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, buffer, pbuffer, 0);
    gst_buffer_unref(gstbuffer);

    return;
}
```

The identity callback that measures fps:

```
static void cb_identity_handoff (GstElement *identity, GstBuffer *buffer, CustomData *data) {
    frame_counter++;
    double diff = (now_ms() - last_time);
    if (diff > 1000){
        LOGD("add frames: %.2f", frame_counter / diff * 1000.0f);
        last_time = now_ms();
        frame_counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving buffers from Java at 30fps for 640X480 stream? It might not be gstreamer issue. It might be because the appsrc might be receiving buffers at lower fps.

Comment: Yes, the `gst_add_stream` method in c is receiving frames at 30fps.

Comment: Then memcpy might be taking time. Just to debug, you can just remove memcpy() call and run. Video content will be junk but it may give some idea. Also, if possible run appsrc ! identity ! fakesink to verify whether the delay is it because of other elements in the pipeline.

Comment: Valid suggestion; I eliminated `byte []` passing between java and c by sending small arrays and manually entering the `gst_buffer_new_allocate` size + removed `memcpy`. I've also tried using a `fakesink` - still slow. Let me see if I can replicate this on a desktop app.

Comment: (1) Since 320*240 gives ~12 fps and 640*480 gives ~2fps, it looks like the system is slow. But i dont understand why as you have removed memcpy. (2) Sometimes I have observed delay in multiple gst_buffer_map/unmap and allocate/free. You can use same buffer always and map it only once. Update it in each process call.

Comment: Good suggestion - I'll try out (2), but I'm doubtful because the running time of the entire function is less than 1ms consistently. Do you also think it could be something to do with PTS/Duration I'm setting? I doubt it because the same timestamps for different buffer sizes function differently.

Comment: If the entire function is taking 1ms, then where the thread is getting blocked? It means the function is not getting called at 30fps from Java right? Measure time at the beginning of the function across calls to confirm that Java is calling your native funcion at 30fps. Dont rely on PTS values of the buffer.

Comment: My hunch is it is stuck somewhere inside `AppSrc`! Java is calling the c `add_stream` function at 30FPS - I've double checked. Why I think it's stuck in `appsrc` is because the `identity` element isn't receiving the frames at the same fps as how often i'm calling the `g_signal_emit_by_name` signal.

Comment: An interesting observation: at 320x240, the identity element receives bursts of data at ~50fps, and then settles back at 12-18fps. I've put up the logs [here](https://pastebin.com/2VNfDgtt)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180336/discussion-between-mayurk-and-crearo-rotar).

Answer (score 0):

You elements are all running in one thread.  Put a *[queue](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-queue.html)* element into your pipeline, from where a all following elements will run in another thread:

```
appsrc ! queue ! identity ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink
```

Comment: A queue will do the same with the added benefit of being able to make them "leaky" by discarding new or old buffers.

Comment: Thanks for that hint.  A buffer element doesn't even exist.